# How to refer to different "sleep time" of multiple people?

Tags: grammatical-number

The lengths of time periods are different.
Should I use "..., whose sleep times are different"? Or just "..., whose sleep time are different"?

Comment: As there are multiple (different) times, then it needs to be plural; ie. "sleep time**s**".

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you intend "sleep time" to refer to (1) the time at which the person goes to bed/sleep; or (2) the duration of their time asleep.  I assume the latter since you refer to "lengths of time periods".  But "sleep duration" would be avoid the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

**Sleep times** if you mean many individual people and want to indicate their individual sleep times are different.

> We don't want the heater to have fixed start and stop times, because people's sleep times are different.

**Sleep time** in the special case of the people being in a different time zone (from the reader) and having a common problem of being different, rather than their individual sleep times being different from each other.

> It was less convenient for British listeners to benefit from the live internet broadcast of the soothing night-time sounds from the Indonesian forest, because their sleep time was some 7 hours different from that of local Indonesians.